# How do I test DelayedJob with Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, delayed-job, webrat

We use DelayedJob to run some of our long running processes and would like to test with Cucumber/Webrat.

Currently, we are calling Delayed::Job.work_off in a Ruby thread to get work done in the background, but are looking for a more robust solution

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks.

Comment: most people use Delayed:Job.work_off .. what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: `Delayed::Job.work_off` is deprecated. Use `Delayed::Worker.new.work_off instead.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see with the `Delayed:Job.work_off` approach is that you are making explicit in your Cucumber scenarios something that belongs to the internals of your system. Mixing both concerns is against the spirit of functional testing:

```
When I click some link # Some operation is launched in the background
And Jobs are dispatched # Delayed:Job.work_off invoked here
Then I should see the results...
```

Another problem is that you populate your Cucumber scenarios with repetitive steps for dispatching jobs when needed.

The approach I am currently using is [launching delayed_job in the background while cucumber scenarios are being executed](http://jorgemanrubia.net/2010/09/01/using-delayed_job-with-cucumber/). You can check the Cucumber hooks I am using in that link.

Comment: the attached blog post implementation starts delayed job, but doesn't actually run them

Comment: The link dead, thats why you should always include a summary of the solution in your answer.